# Como desativar cache de servidor Godaddy?

Tags: php, apache, cache

Estou com um problema com cache de servidor no Godaddy.
Não sei se isso é com todos os clientes do Godaddy com servidor compartilhado ou apenas com a minha conta.

Acontece que eu faço alterações num arquivo e faço o upload, mas a alteração só é refletida depois de alguns minutos. Isso inviabiliza a programação.

Pesquisei e encontrei algumas informações sobre APC no php.ini, mas eu não tenho acesso a esse arquivo em minha conta.

Existe alguma forma de mudar isso?

Comment: Será [disto](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7910/disabling-apc-on-your-hosting-account) que anda à procura?

Answer (score 4):

Fizeste referência ao `php.ini` na tua pergunta apesar de não teres utilizado a tag `PHP`.

Para o caso de estares a utilizar PHP, ficam os cabeçalhos para instruir os navegadores e servidores proxy que não devem fazer cache da tua página:

```php
<?php

// define data de expiração da página no passado
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");

// define a data de ultima actualização para "agora"
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

// indica aos navegadores e proxies para não fazerem cache da página
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// teu código depois dos headers...
?>
```

Desta forma será sempre servida uma cópia nova da tua página em cada acesso!

---

Saber mais sobre a função [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) do PHP <sup>Inglês</sup>

> header() is used to send a raw HTTP header. See the [»HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616) for more information on HTTP headers.
>
> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Que traduzido:

> header() é utilizada para enviar um cabeçalho HTTP em bruto. Ver a [»especificação HTTP/1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616) para mais informações sobre cabeçalhos HTTP.
>
> Lembre-se que header() deve ser chamado antes de qualquer saída real ser enviada, seja por tags HTML normais, linhas em branco num arquivo, ou a partir de PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Com** `.htaccess` **(que é o recomendado)**

> Antes de tudo, crie um arquivo chamado `.htaccess` e envie para a raiz do seu site (public_html).

---

### Controle o Cache

Dentro do arquivo insira o seguinte código:

```
#5 dias de cache
# O cabeçalho "pragma" é para compatibilidade com o IE
<FilesMatch "(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=432000, public, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "max-age=432000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

> Dessa forma quando uma pessoa acessar o seu site, ficará armazenado o cache durante 5 dias, após se passar 5 dias, se a pessoa acessar novamente, o cache será atualizado, ou seja, será baixado uma nova versão do seu cache.

No exemplo acima, foi dado 5 dias de cache. Veja abaixo outros exemplos.

Antes de prosseguir saiba, **`um dia tem 86.400 segundos`**.

Ou seja, se você quiser que o cache dure somente 2 dias, multiplique **2x 86400 segundos** que é igual a: **172800** segundos.

Então no código acima substitua: `"max-age=432000` por `"max-age=172800` e **seu cache durará 2 dias.**

---

## Desativando o Cache

> Para desativar o cache basta substituir no primeiro código citado `"max-age=432000` por `"max-age=0` desta forma você terá seu **Cache desativado.**

O exemplo final ficará:

```
#Sem cache
# O cabeçalho "pragma" é para compatibilidade com o IE
<FilesMatch "(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "max-age=0, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

---

**Observação:** eu configurei no código acima somente para arquivos `.css` e `.js` *(que é o que geralmente é mantido como cache)*,

Caso você queira adicionar mais extensões, como **imagens**, etc...

Basta você adicionar no código acima a extensão desejada, mais precisamente em:

```
<FilesMatch "(css|js)$">
```

Para adicionar imagens as configurações de cache basta deixá-lo assim:

```
<FilesMatch "(css|js|png|jpeg|ico|gif)$">
```

Você deverá separar as extensões com `|`.